# paintComponent is stressing me out; Hangman programming project

Tags: java, object, paint, paintcomponent

I have a programming project implementing the Hangman game. I can only paint certain parts of the hangman at a time, which is dependent on the amount of incorrect tries by the user. The teacher of my programming class requires the creation of the hangman drawing to be in a different class.

The problem I'm having is sending over the number of incorrect tries to a class with the `paintComponent`.

```
if(updatedChallenge == challenge)
    {
        incorrectTries += 1;
    }
    challenge = updatedChallenge;
```

The `challenge == updatedChallenge` refers to the hidden word before the user's guess and the hidden word after the user's guess. If they are still equal that means the user made an incorrect choice. 1 gets added to the total number of incorrect tries.

Here is my other class:

```
class HangmanPicture extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(250, 300, 300, 300); //Platform

        g.drawLine(275, 300, 275, 200); //Pole

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawLine(275, 200, 350, 200); //Rope

        g.drawLine(350, 200, 350, 225); //Noose

        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawOval(350, 225, 15, 15); //Head

        g.drawLine(350, 230, 350, 260); //Torso

        g.drawLine(350, 240, 340, 230); //Left Arm

        g.drawLine(350, 240, 360, 230); // Right Arm

        g.drawLine(350, 260, 330, 280); // Left Leg

        g.drawLine(350, 260, 390, 280); // Right Leg
    }
}
```

I want to put an `if` statement where each body part gets added after each incorrect try, which requires me to send the number of incorrect tries to the class. Whenever I try to send the number, it always somehow interferes with `paintComponent`.

Comment: The code does not show "send[ing] the number". Make sure to read (and research) any compiler error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending the `JPanel` class, we can add extra methods and fields to the class and use them where `HangmanPicture` is being used.

```
HangmanPicture panel = new HangmanPicture();
  ...
  if(updatedChallenge == challenge)
  {
      panel.addIncorrectAttempt();
  }
  challenge = updatedChallenge; 


class HangmanPicture extends JPanel
{
    private int incorrectAttempts = 0;

    // Add one to counter
    public void addIncorrectAttempt(){
      incorrectAttempte++;
    }

    // Get how many times the player entered an incorrect number
    public int getIncorrectAttempts(){
      return incorrectAttempts;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if( incorrectAttempts >= 1 ){
          g.drawLine(250, 300, 300, 300); //Platform
        }

        if( incorrectAttempts >= 2 ){
          g.drawLine(275, 300, 275, 200); //Pole
        }
    }
}
```